# Can I customise QuestDB web-console logo?

Tags: questdb

I would like replace inbuilt `Q` logo with custom company branded logo.

[image]

Is there an easy way QuestDB update logo?

Answer (score 1):

my friend at the moment it is **not possible** to customize the logo in the web console

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to update the logo you'll have to navigate to the root directory, this is different depending on your operating system: https://questdb.io/docs/reference/command-line-options/#default-root-directory

If you replace the favicon.ico / favicon.svg in the 'public/assets' folder, the icon will change on the web console. However I am not sure if this change will be kept when you upgrade to a newer version.

Answer (score 1):

If you replace the `favicon.ico/favicon.svg` in the `public/assets` folder, the icon will change on the web console, but it won't affect the original application once its upgraded.